# Monkeypatch array and set the array elements to a new value

Tags: ruby

I am writing a new method for Array, i.e.

```
class Array

  def my_new_method!
     ...
     other_array = ....
     # Want to set self to other_array. How?

  end

end
```

As the comments indicate, I calculate inside `Array#my_new_method!` a new array, `other_array` (which in my case happens to have **the same number of elements** as `self`), and I want to set all elements of the Array represented by `self` to the respective element from `other_array`. Of course I could do a

```
other_array.each_with_index |element, i|
  self[i] = element
end
```

but maybe there is a simpler way? I looked up the methods `map!` and `fill` which seem to go into a similar directions, but can't see how I could apply them reasonably in my case.

For example, if I have

```
a=[2,6,4]
```

and I do a

```
a.my_new_method!
```

and inside `my_new_method!`, `other_array` would turn out to be [1,2,3], I would like that a is then also [1,2,3]. This example looks a bit artificial, because if `my_new_method!` would not be an instance method of Array, but some external Method,

```
a = my_new_method(a)
```

would do the job. In my case, this does not help, because I can not do a

```
self = other_array
```

inside `my_new_method!`.

Comment: What would be given input and a expected output?

Comment: @SebastianPalma : I have added this information. Sorry, thought it were self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-replace) to replace your array's content with the content of another array:

```
class Array
  def my_new_method!
    other = [1, 2, 3]
    replace(other)
  end
end

a = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
a.my_new_method!
a #=> [1, 2, 3]
```